# IE8 MIME type application/json not found

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I have an app that returns JSON data from an ajax request with the MIME type 'application/json'.  In IE8, it throws an error that the MIME type is not found.

Is there anyway around this, other than changing the MIME type to text/plain?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What always works, for me at least, is setting the request header to receive `*/*`, and including `json2.js` for IE<9, which can be found [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Then in the callback function just `JSON.parse(this.responseText);` and you should be ok

Comment: So I have `*/*` in the request header and json2, but it's still prompting me for download.

Comment: How are you setting MIME type?

Comment: could you post some code, are you using an `XMLHttpRequest` object or a `try-catch` block and an `ActiveXObject` for your request? How are you setting the request header, it sould be `yourAjaxObject.setRequestHeader('Accept','*/*');`, and, of course: `yourAjaxObject.onreadystatechange = callbackReference`

Comment: Sending requests using `setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');` is not as easy in IE8, so best stick to `x-www-form-urlencoded` when it comes to sending them.

Comment: I have a few methods that use this, one is a jQuery plugin, another is Backbone.js, another is jQuery's standard ajax.getJSON.  I've gone ahead and just stringified the output and set the MIME as text/plain, then parse it.  Thanks a lot though!